# Polymer core-header-panel horizontal scrolling with min-width

Tags: html, css, polymer, horizontal-scrolling

I have built a SPA with Polymer for a VST-like Audio Application. To keep the app consistent for small screen resolutions, I had to put a min-width on the main `core-header-panel`. However, when you go beyond the limits, you don't get the horizontal scroll-bar in your browser, and have no way to reach the out of bounds material.

Any idea on how to sort this out?
Thanks for reading and all the best.

Answer (score 0):

`@media` css rule might help.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    core-header-panel {
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Adi for your soon answer. However, it's unfortunately not working on my side.